# How to get the names of applications seen on home screen in android?

Tags: android

I want to create a list of applications seen on the home screen in android.

Presently i am using the following code :

```
 List<ApplicationInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
```

But this returns all the installed applications but i require only the applications having icons on the home screen.

How can this be done?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you planning to accommodate users of non-standard Launchers? Watch out for Sense and TouchWiz which come as standard on a lot of phones.

Comment: "Home screen" is not a standard concept in Android. As @Emyr said, a lot of people are using different launcher replacements, so their homescreens are not the same as the "stock" one. And every launcher has its own way of storing what is displayed on the home screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've got the list of packages installed on your device, iterate through them and call [`getLaunchIntentForPackage()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29) on each item.

If a valid intent is returned, it exists on the Launcher, else if null is returned, the package does not launch from the Launcher screen. Note that Home screen shortcuts are a subset of the Launcher apps.

Comment: Thanks. I have done the same. But it gives a system exception on some packages. How can that be resolved?

Comment: Document says it will return Returns Intent that can be used to launch the main activity in the  . so usually all apps have 1 launcher . so i dont think this will work ........did you tried this ever ??

Comment: @Shail It returns the intent for `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`. If any activity falls under the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` They will be visible on the Launcher. 
`

Comment: @Reno its not working at all,I agreed with Shailendra that its returning all the apps which contains atleast 1 launcher activity ,rather than the apps seen on home screen.

Comment: this answer does not respond to the question, the author is asking "apps on home screen" not "Laucher apps".